# Convert negative binary number to decimal

Tags: c++, binary, twos-complement

For example:

```
string binaryValue = "11111111111111111111111111111011" // -5
```

I need to convert this string to decimal representatin of this number.

```
stoi(binaryValue, nullptr, 2)
```

Will throw exception on this case. So how can i do this in c++ ? String or int doesn't matter.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: `Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x00BDF664.
`

Comment: Your conversion depends on 2-complement representation, which is not part of C++ standard. Thus the number is out of range. Use `stol` and force convert to `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) of:

```
int  std::stoi( const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos = 0, int base = 10 );
```

in particular:

> The valid integer value [of `str`] consists of the following parts:
>
> - (optional) plus or minus sign
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> If the minus sign was part of the input sequence, the numeric value calculated
>   from the sequence of digits is negated as if by unary minus in the result type.
>
> **Exceptions**
>
> - `std::invalid_argument` if no conversion could be performed
> - `std::out_of_range` if the converted value would fall out of the range of
>     the result type...

In the absence of a preceding minus-sign, the string:

```
std::string binaryValue = "11111111111111111111111111111011";
```

will be interpreted in a the call:

```
std::stoi(binaryValue, nullptr, 2);
```

as a non-negative integer value in base-2 representation. But as such,
it is out of range, so `std::out_of_range` is thrown:

To represent -5 as a string that your `std::stoi` call will convert as you expect,
use:

```
std::string const binaryValue = "-101";
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fecad81316f01b0)

If you don't want to prefix a minus sign to a non-negative base-2 numeral, or cannot do so in your real-world
situation, but wish to interpret `"11111111111111111111111111111011"`
as the two's complement representation of a signed integer using the `std::sto*` API,
then you must first convert the string to an *unsigned* integer of a wide-enough
type, and then convert that unsigned value to a signed one. E.g.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto ul = std::stoul("11111111111111111111111111111011",nullptr,2);
    std::cout << ul << std::endl;
    int i = ul;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be900a37557d2b4c)

Comment: The result of converting from `unsigned` to `int`, where the value is too large to store in `int`, is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

as you probably know number are stored as Twos Complement
to convert it using simple pseudocode

> flip numbers 0->1, 1->0 from left to write util you find last 1 in string don't toggle this one

this will be your answer
0000000000000000000000000101=5

here is the code brouht from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/efficient-method-2s-complement-binary-string/

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


string findTwoscomplement(string str)
{


  int n = str.length();


// Traverse the string to get first '1' from
// the last of string
int i;
for (i = n ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    if (str[i] == '1')
        break;

// If there exists no '1' concat 1 at the
// starting of string
if (i == 0)
    return '1' + str;

// Continue traversal after the position of
// first '1'
for (int k = i-1 ; k >= 0; k--)
{
    //Just flip the values
    if (str[k] == '1')
        str[k] = '0';
    else
        str[k] = '1';
}

// return the modified string
return str;;
}



int main()
{
    string str = "11111111111111111111111111111011";
    cout << findTwoscomplement(str);
//now you convert it to decimal if you want
    cout<<"Hello World";
    cout << stoul( findTwoscomplement(str),nullptr,2);
        return 0;


     }
```

preview at https://onlinegdb.com/SyFYLVtdf

Comment: okay, -25 = "11111111111111111111111111100111" , 25 = "00000000000000000000000000011001" and your solution doesnt' work for me.

Comment: i brought  implantation from geeksforgeeks ,if it love it please accepts answer